# Flutter can't find devices. Ditto from inside AndroidStudio. "adb not responding" but killing task doesn't help. flutter doctor throws exception

Tags: flutter

I'm using both Windows 10 and MacOS 10.13.6

The same problem started happening on both machines, and I don't think i made any change that triggered the problem. It just spontaneously broken on Win 10 and MacOS within 12 hours of each other.

Running AndroidStudio, the devices pulldown won't show plugged in Android phone, and then the devices pulldown disappears. This happend on both platforms.

flutter run also fails with "adb not responding"
I've killed adb using Task Manager, adb kill-server, taskkill /F /IM adb*, killall adb 
and restarted it with adb devices. adb devices output looks fine:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
5VT7N15A29001392        device
```

Flutter doctor from Windows 10:

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[v] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.285], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.8.2 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 5ab9e70727 (4 weeks ago), 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
    • Engine revision 58a1894a1c
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

[v] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Susannah\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-P, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studo_3_2_beta2\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[v] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 29.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 181.5616
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[v] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studo_3_2_beta2
    • Flutter plugin version 29.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 181.5616
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b04)

[v] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.3
    • Flutter plugin version 29.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 182.4323.44

adb not responding

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
#1      AndroidDevice._getProperty (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:98:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AndroidDevice.targetPlatform (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:129:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Device.descriptions (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:303:58)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      DeviceValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:657:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:105:56)
#6      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:183:42)
#7      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#8      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:173:24)
#9      DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:29:39)
#10     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#11     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:28:42)
#12     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:372:18)
#13     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#16     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#17     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#18     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#19     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#20     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#21     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#22     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#23     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#24     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#25     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#26     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#27     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#28     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Flutter doctor on Mac:

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 0.8.2 at /Users/susannahmedley/Documents/development/flutter
• Framework revision 5ab9e70727 (4 weeks ago), 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
• Engine revision 58a1894a1c
• Dart version 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/susannahmedley/Library/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/susannahmedley/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 10.0, Build version 10A255
• ios-deploy 1.9.2
• CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 28.0.2
• Dart plugin version 181.5616
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2.3)
• IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
• Flutter plugin version 28.0.4
• Dart plugin version 182.4323.44

[!] Connected devices
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Even though the device is connected.

Update: The Mac works with an Android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Inexplicably, it started working again, after several reboots. Anyone know what could have caused this?